# How can I alias ("typedef") a concrete instance of a generic class?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Let's say we have a generic container…

```
class GenericContainer<T> {
  constructor(val:T) {
    this.val = val;
  }
}
let numberContainer = new GenericContainer<number>();
```

I would like to be able to create a "shorthand" alias: a concrete type of the generic class using `number`, called `NumberContainer`. I would like it to be usable as a drop-in replacement for `GenericContainer<number>`.

I would also like to avoid the type alias showing up in the built JavaScript. So references to `NumberContainer` in typescript should appear as `GenericContainer`.

```
// I have tried...
type NumberContainer = GenericContainer<number>;  
interface NumberContainer extends GenericContainer<number>;
```

But anytime I try to use it…

```
let numberContainer = new NumberContainer();
```

I get an error: `'NumberContainer' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`

I notice I can extend with an empty class, which compiles. Like:

```
class NumberContainer extends GenericContainer<number> {}
// compiles to:
//   class NumberContainer extends GenericContainer {
//   }
```

But this emits an actual JS class declaration into the build, which I want to avoid because it seems useless. I want to have NumberContainer be able to be instantiated (with the GenericContainer class implementation in JS), but otherwise have no purpose than type checking.

Is this kind of type-only "aliasing" possible in TypeScript? Or what am I not understanding?

Comment: You'll need to use either `let numberContainer: NumberContainer = new GenericContainer();` (where `NumberContainer` is a type), or `const NumberContainer = GenericContainer<number>;` (where `NumberContainer` is a value)

Comment: You can get both a named type and a named value with `type NumberContainer = Container<number>; const NumberContainer = Container<number>;` but you can't avoid having some JS emitted.  If you want `new NumberContainer(3)` to work, then there will need to be something named `NumberContainer` at runtime.  It's unavoidable (although it can just be `const NumberContainer = GenericContainer` at runtime, not a separate class declaration) Does that make sense? I can write up an answer explaining more if so. Otherwise, what am I missing?  (Pls mention @jcalz if you reply so I'm notified.)